# select command for access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

```
OleDbCommand cmdpic = new OleDbCommand
          ("select * from sub_category where id_s=" 
            + Request.QueryString["id_s"] 
            +"or"+"order by sub_id desc", concars);
```

it shows error

what is the correct command

Comment: What error?  THe more details you provide teh more liekly you are to get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think the real error was putting in the `OR` in the first place.  The missing spaces would have caused a problem, but that was invalid syntax anyway -- `select x from y where a=b or order by z` is not valid in any SQL I have heard of.

Answer (score 0):

OleDbCommand cmdpic = new OleDbCommand
          ("select * from sub_category where id_s=" 
            + Request.QueryString["id_s"] 
            +" or "+"order by sub_id desc", concars);

I believe you forgot spaces in the `"Or"`

And providing the error message is of course very helpful :)

Edit: It appears you should remove the OR indeed.

Comment: "select * from sub_category where id_s=" + Request.QueryString["id_s"] + "or" + "order by sub_id desc"

its not working please give me correct command

Comment: i am success to do it 
"select * from sub_category where id_s=" + Request.QueryString["id_s"] + "  order by sub_id desc

Answer (score 0):

```
 Request.QueryString["id_s"] 
        +"or"+"order by sub_id desc"
```

You have no spaces in there. Try this:

```
OleDbCommand cmdpic = new OleDbCommand
      ("select * from sub_category where id_s=" 
        + Request.QueryString["id_s"] 
        +" or "+"order by sub_id desc", concars);
```

Comment: it shows error Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'id_s=10ororder by sub_id desc'.

Source Error:

Comment: Are you sure you subbed in the command at the bottom of what I wrote? That error message still shows the query as having no spaces in it.